# Connect to Postgres container with PhpStorm

Tags: postgresql, docker, phpstorm

I would like to access my Postgres database (docker container) from PhpStorm.

docker-compose.yml

```
# Run docker-compose build
# Run docker-compose up
# Live long and prosper

version: '3.1'
services:
  apache:
    build: .docker/apache
    container_name: sf-apache
    ports:
      - 82:80
    volumes:
      - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${SYMFONY_APP}:/home/wwwroot/sf3
    depends_on:
      - php

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    image: 'postgres:12.6'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=${PGSQL_ADMIN_USER}"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PGSQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - ./API/var/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - .docker/postgresql/init-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
```

My PhpStorm config :
[image]

I can access to my database via `docker exec -it postgres bash`

Answer (score 1):

If php storm is on the same host then you need to use `localhost`. If both phpstorm and pg is part of the same compose file , then you would use the service name since both would be in the same virtual network

Comment: i used `localhost` and `postgres` (my service nane)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The host should be localhost.

Comment: I see a database init script , is  the database getting created before you are trying to connect

Comment: @Hisham, i don't think the host should be localhost if my postgres server is distant.

Comment: @abhishekphukan, all seems to be ok.

Comment: Did you change the host and url both to point to localhost ?

Comment: @abhishekphukan yes, database `mcp_database` not found.....

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I have a Postgres local and a Postgres with docker. My Postgres local get the upper hand on my docker Postgres. I have killed the service and put the container service name on it.

Works perfectly.

Thanks for you help,

Answer (score -1):

Go in PhpStorm on the database container and mouse right click inspect container search the real port is named HostPort.

Enter the real HostPort in PhpStorm configuration and ist work

[image]

show this article below for additional info's

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-a-dbms-image.html#connect_to_psql

It is a liftle bit confused i search self on hour for understand that the port set in the docker-compose file is only for the internal conection from pdo-driver.
For Connection from outside into the container you need the HostPort-

Comment: Please add all text content **in text form**, not hidden in a screenshot